# Access Tkinter window variables from another GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

Have two scripts with a simple Tkinter GUI that does some data processing and visualization, and I need them to communicate.

Each script has a layout like this (a very simplified version):

```py
from tkinter import *
import additional_files

begin = Tk()

def interface():
    begin.mainloop()
    sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()

def some_function():
    textBox.insert('1.0', 'Hello!')

textBox=Text(begin)
button=Button(begin, text="Say hello", command=lambda: some_function())

textBox.grid(row=0)
button.grid(row =1)

interface()
```

Each script also has several additional files with functions that they use (these sets of files do not intersect).
I have the following directory layout:

```
|-- root
    |-- gui1.py    # Script 1
    |-- add_func1_1.py
    |-- add_func1_2.py
    |-- gui2.py    # Script 2
    |-- add_func2_1.py
    |-- add_func2_2.py
```

I need to have both scripts open simultaneously and then, for example, if I push a certain button in `Window_1` a Text field in a `Window_2` would be filled with data from the `Window_1` entry. So, in short, I need to pass variable values between these two scripts.

I tried to add `import gui2` in gui1 and call `gui2.interface()` in the gui1 `interface()` function but then only `gui2` window opens (I need both `gui1` and `gui2` windows). I also tried to get the value of the `gui2` variable by `gui2.variable` and it didn't have any effect at all.

I could rewrite both scripts into one, but at this point, they are quite large and it would be really messy, so I'd rather avoid doing that.

Edit: I use Ubuntu 22.04.1, Python 3.10

Comment: Not a trivial problem. Two approaches. 1. One GUI opens the other as a child so they are in the same python process and can share information directly. 2. Use some form of interprocess communication such as sockets to share information.

Comment: Please post some OS and Python version information.